# Is there any "jQuery boilerplate" to enable/disable buttons?

Tags: jquery, html

### The goal

Enable/disable buttons (yes, with HTML tag `disabled`) in a practical and simple way.

### The problem

I know not a consistent and simple way to enable and disable buttons with jQuery/JavaScript. People's actions on my application are well filtered and I use and abuse of disabled buttons. I really need a "recursive-way" to do the magic that I want.

To be more specific, I know how to disable a button with jQuery, but how can I do this many times?

### Update v1: More details

I think it is not very clear for you, so I'll explain.

**I know how to disable/enable a button with jQuery or JavaScript.** But there are many buttons to be enabled or disabled on my application. What I need is simple: a good way to do this using the DRY's (**D** on't **R** epeat **Y** ourself) concept.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, at least for me.

Comment: What you mean Several times? If you have a function is can be used as many times as you wish, just make it a trigger on a element with a specific class. Show us what you got

Comment: I have edited my post. See it now.

Comment: @chiefGui that doesn't help. Enabling and disabling a button is already very dry. It's a function, and you can call it as many times as you need.

Comment: @KevinB Hmm... Seriously? I was disabling buttons with "attr" from jQuery and not feel some consistency. >_<

Comment: `.attr()` is for attributes, `disabled` is a property.

Comment: See, if you included code, we could have pointed out that flaw much quicker.

Comment: DO NOT DO `$('mybutton').removeAttr('disabled')` - or you cannot re-enable the button - the property with `.prop()` management is proper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `.prop()` method:

```
// Disable
$('#element').prop('disabled', true);

// Enable
$('#element').prop('disabled', false);
```

Notes:

- Element should have `disabled` property in the DOM.
- You can disable and enable the element **infinite** times.

Edit: You can also toggle the `disabled` state:

```
$('.elements').prop('disabled', function(_, disabled) {
    return !disabled;
});
```

Comment: which is the most consistent way using newer versions of jquery

Comment: This is the best way to do this?

Comment: @chiefGui yes this is pretty much as easy and simple you can get it.

Comment: @chiefGui It's the only way to do it, short of using `document.getElementByID("element").disabled = true;//false`

Comment: Oh, thank you gentlemen. I did not know that. And @KevinB, with the "attr" from jQuery is possible too, isn't?

Comment: @chiefGui Only the first time, after that it won't work because `disabled` is not an attribute.

Comment: @KevinB Oh, thanks Kevin! I didn't know that. Sorry about the ignorant question, but I haven't found another way than the Stack.